# Open Source USB Flash Drive Circuit Anywhere?

Tags: flash-memories

I would like to make a removable USB flash drive from scratch. I would probably start from component selection. And because this is not as exciting as some other DIY projects, I haven't found any reference designs I can follow. Is there a resource you can recommend to find a schematic of a usb flash drive so i can look at it as a reference design

Thank you!

Comment: Almost any USB-enabled MCU can be used for this. It's just a matter of getting the descriptors right and connecting the flash.

Comment: Doh. Somehow I was expecting something special. I guess I really have to start from scratch though!

Comment: I found a couple USB 3.0 MCUs:

Comment: 1. TI TUSB9260 (USB 3.0 to SATA only?)
2. Cypress EZ-USB-FX3 
I will update with design specs for these MCUs, as well as MCUs from other vendors when I find them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a shopping question, because it is, and because the goal is effectively pointless.  There is no reason to make a one-off of an *actual* flash drive, as manufacturers who negotiate with parts suppliers do a much better job.  For a unique related but in some way fundamentally distinct application, a general purpose MCU should be used, **however no such specific requirement has been stated**, so the only *justified* interpretation of the question is missing the information that would make it answerable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton It would be good if you don't try to discourage hobbyists/entrepreneurs trying something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last of the "easy to find, easy to obtain datasheet" was the [SMSC USB97C242](http://www.keil.com/dd/docs/datashts/smsc/usb97c242.pdf).  As memory sizes rapidly increased it was obsoleted a few years after its 2002 introduction.

Closest thing to that you will find today is a dedicated USB to SD card controller. USB2240 comes to mind.  Use with commonly found SD Cards. You could use a eMMC NAND memory device (which has built in wear leveling) if you wanted to create a custom board and print a custom enclosure.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like a solid MCU for this project. The product page has similar products listed: http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=USB2240

Unfortunately it does not list any "superspeed" USB3 devices. And I can't seem to find a superspeed capable MCU (weird). So USB2240 might just do it.